# Add while loop to spacy component

Tags: spacy

In one of my other questions I asked about processing multiple strings in a nlp pipeline.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

nlp.add_pipe("rebel", after="senter", config={
    'device':-1, # Number of the GPU, -1 if want to use CPU
    'model_name':'Babelscape/rebel-large'} # Model used, will default to 'Babelscape/rebel-large' if not given
    )
input_sentence = 'Too Heavy and Poor weld quality,', 'difficult mount', 'just got it installed', 'Decent Little Reader, Poor Tablet', 'Ok For What It Is'

i=0

while i < len(input_sentence):
    doc = nlp(input_sentence[i])
    i = i + 1

# (0, 8): {'relation': 'located in the administrative territorial entity', 'head_span': Gràcia, 'tail_span': Barcelona}
# (0, 10): {'relation': 'country', 'head_span': Gràcia, 'tail_span': Spain}
# (8, 0): {'relation': 'contains administrative territorial entity', 'head_span': Barcelona, 'tail_span': Gràcia}
# (8, 10): {'relation': 'country', 'head_span': Barcelona, 'tail_span': Spain}
# (17, 0): {'relation': 'located in the administrative territorial entity', 'head_span': Vila de Gràcia, 'tail_span': Gràcia}
# (21, 0): {'relation': 'located in the administrative territorial entity', 'head_span': Vallcarca i els Penitents, 'tail_span': Gràcia}
# (26, 0): {'relation': 'located in the administrative territorial entity', 'head_span': El Coll, 'tail_span': Gràcia}
# (29, 0): {'relation': 'located in the administrative territorial entity', 'head_span': La Salut, 'tail_span': Gràcia}
# (0, 46): {'relation': 'shares border with', 'head_span': Gràcia, 'tail_span': Eixample}
# (0, 51): {'relation': 'shares border with', 'head_span': Gràcia, 'tail_span': Sarrià-Sant Gervasi}
# (0, 59): {'relation': 'shares border with', 'head_span': Gràcia, 'tail_span': Horta-Guinardó}
# (46, 0): {'relation': 'shares border with', 'head_span': Eixample, 'tail_span': Gràcia}
# (46, 51): {'relation': 'shares border with', 'head_span': Eixample, 'tail_span': Sarrià-Sant Gervasi}
# (51, 0): {'relation': 'shares border with', 'head_span': Sarrià-Sant Gervasi, 'tail_span': Gràcia}
# (51, 46): {'relation': 'shares border with', 'head_span': Sarrià-Sant Gervasi, 'tail_span': Eixample}
# (51, 59): {'relation': 'shares border with', 'head_span': Sarrià-Sant Gervasi, 'tail_span': Horta-Guinardó}
```

As you can see I added a while loop to be able to process the multiple strings. Unfortunately I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'start'

Anyone knows how this can be solved?

The whole notebook can be found in the following link:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13DCfzBNFQ7nYn4zAq72nYKxz_S39SjST?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a small bug in spacey_component.py:set_annotations:https://github.com/Babelscape/rebel/blob/2eb4a3445c5f64b3be77f13e0122fff8c6d7d3cc/spacy_component.py that occurs if the model returns an entity that is not in the text. (Possibly triggered by a new line at the end of the text.) The alternative below works for me.

```
    def set_annotations(self, doc: Doc, triplets: List[dict]):
        """
        The function takes a spacy Doc object and a list of triplets (dictionaries) as input.
        For each triplet, it finds the substring in the Doc object that matches the head and tail of the triplet.
        It then creates a spacy span object for each of the head and tail.
        Finally, it creates a dictionary of the relation type, head span and tail span and adds it to the Doc object

        :param doc: the spacy Doc object
        :type doc: Doc
        :param triplets: List[dict]
        :type triplets: List[dict]
        """
        for triplet in triplets:
            # get substring to spacy span
            head_span = re.search(triplet["head"], doc.text)
            tail_span = re.search(triplet["tail"], doc.text)
            # get spacy span
            head_span_start = tail_span_start = -1
            if head_span is not None:
                head_span = doc.char_span(head_span.start(), head_span.end())
                head_span_start = head_span.start
            else:
                head_span = triplet["head"]
            if tail_span is not None:
                tail_span = doc.char_span(tail_span.start(), tail_span.end())
                tail_span_start = tail_span.start
            else:
                tail_span = triplet["tail"]
            offset = (head_span_start, tail_span_start)
            if offset not in doc._.rel:
                doc._.rel[offset] = {
                    "relation": triplet["type"],
                    "head_span": head_span,
                    "tail_span": tail_span,
                }
```